# Visa for U.S. citizen permanently staying in France for religious purposes?

Tags: usa, visa, france, dual-citizenship, religion

How does one apply for a religious visa for permanent stay in France? What are the requirements? What is such a French visa called? Does it help to have EU dual-citizenship (e.g., Italian-American dual-citizenship)?

Comment: If you are an Italian citizen, you don't require a visa.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Any EU country citizen can stay permanently in any other EU country without a visa?

Answer (score 2):

As an Italian citizen, you do not need and you cannot get a visa to enter France (unless you don't tell them about your Italian citizenship and instead apply with your US passport).  This is because of the freedom of movement of persons established in European Union law.

As a US citizen, you would apply for the visa through the appropriate French consulate.  The details of the application process depend on the reason for your stay in France and on its duration.  Details are available (in French) at https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F16162.

The corresponding page for EU citizens is https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2651

If you already have an Italian passport or Identity card, or if you can get one relatively quickly because your Italian citizenship has already been recognized by the Italian government, it will be far easier just to do that.  If you expect the process will take longer than getting a long-stay visa on your US passport, then you may want to get the visa instead.

Comment: (+1) It might useful to add that the specific visa for this situation is (possibly confusingly) called a [*visiteur* visa or permit](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F302). It's not really ”permanent” but it is renewable.

Comment: @Relaxed thanks.  I couldn't figure out which visa applies here, so perhaps you should add your own answer.